# Workstation shutdowns automatically and shows no bootable device

Tags: hard-drive, boot, windows-8.1, dell-precision

I have Dell Precision T1700 workstation, a new machine, with 512 Hybrid disk. Recently I added an old 1TB HDD to it. After adding HDD am facing following problems.

If I work on Workstation for hour together, then there won't be any problem. But if I leave my Workstation unattended for a while (time varies from 15 minutes to hours) and come back to the Workstation, a black screen with following error message shows up

```
No bootable devices found.
Press F1 key to retry boot.
Press F2 key for setup utility.
Press F5 key to run onboard diagnostics.
```

I called Dell regarding this issue. They made me to use system for a 4 days without extra 1 TB HDD. In that period I didn't face these issue. They came to conclusion that issue is due to incompatibility with 1TB HDD.

I am just curious, what kind of incompatibility can happen? Why error happens only when Workstation is unattended?

Comment: Is the system set to go to sleep after a while? If that's the case try modifying your current power plan so the system doesn't go to sleep, then see if the problem still crops up. Also confirm your old HDD has no errors, and if you used an old SATA cable try a new one instead.

Comment: Put to sleep is set to never. SATA cable is new. Yes I have to check for HDD error. Will check that come back.